# Can any one tell me how this is a strategy pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

In this below code basically three 3 main classes

- 1 classes that implements Operation interface
- 2 Classes that extents from Context class
- 3 Main class that demonstrate Strategy pattern

---

So my question is that how is this a strategy pattern apply in this code

---

Operation interface

```
public interface Operation { 
    public float run(float a,float b);
}
```

Add class

```
public class Add implements Operation{ 
    @Override
    public float run(float a, float b) {
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

Multiply class

```
public class Multiply implements Operation {
    @Override
    public float run(float a, float b) {
        return a*b;
    }
}
```

Subtract class

```
public class Subtract implements Operation {
    @Override
    public float run(float a, float b) {
        return a-b;
    }
}
```

Context class

```
public abstract class Context {
    protected Operation OP;

    public abstract float run(float a,float b);
}
```

AddContext class

```
public class AddContext extends Context {
    public AddContext(){
        OP = new Add();
    }
    @Override
    public float run(float a, float b) {
        return OP.run(a,b);
    }
}
```

MultiplyContext class

```
public class MultiplyContext extends Context {
    public MultiplyContext(){
        OP = new Multiply();
    }
    @Override
    public float run(float a, float b) {
        return OP.run(a,b);
    }
}
```

SubtractContest class

```
public class SubtractContext extends Context {
    public SubtractContext(){
        OP = new Subtract();
    }
    @Override
    public float run(float a, float b) {
        return OP.run(a,b);
    }
}
```

Main class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... o){
// 1st Strategy        
        Context c = new AddContext();
        System.out.println(c.run(1,2));

// 2nd Strategy
        c = new SubtractContext();
        System.out.println(c.run(1,2));

// 3rd Strategy
         c = new MultiplyContext();
        System.out.println(c.run(1,2));
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing i see is the mindless redundancy of `...Context` classes.

Comment: How do you know that it is strategy pattern ? Any references ? I could not see anything in those lines

Comment: because it is in my mid term paper

Comment: plz check this is a modify version of { https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm }

Comment: `Operation` and its implementors are a classic example of `Strategy`. The caller only sees `Operation` and various strategies perform different types of operation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is Strategy pattern. Of course, Marko is right, Context classes are completely redundant. What is the reason to have them?

Classes Add, Multiply, Subtract are strategies, because they define what actually do with arguments, but not on them-selves. Pseudo code can be like:
 If operation is Add then use Add strategy 
 Else if operation is Multiply then use Multiply strategy and so on...

It is better to call classes properly (i.e. AddStrategy, MultiplyStrategy) and instead of Context it is better to be (Controller or Processor if you'd like) and it's code can look like:

```
public class Controller()
{
   private Operation addStrategy = new AddStrategy();
   private Operation multiplyStrategy = new MultiplyStrategy();
   private Operation subtractStrategy = new SubtractStrategy();


   public float runOperation(String op,float a, float b)
   {
     Operation requestedStrategy;
     switch (op)
     {
       case "+":              
            requestedStrategy = addStrategy;
            break;
       case "*":              
            requestedStrategy = multiplyStrategy;
            break;
       case "-":              
            requestedStrategy = subtractStrategy;
            break;
       default:
            throw new Exception("Unsupported operation");
     }

     return requestedStrategy.run(a,b);
   }
}
```

So, it is classical Strategy pattern.

Comment: Better yet, `operationMap.get(opSymbol).run(a, b)`

Comment: sure, there are many ways. I just tried to make it more clear readable, rather than better running :)

Comment: actually your approach may be faster, but my suggested approach is more readable.

Comment: yes it is... :) and in real life map is much better - I almost always use your approach, because usually strategies are not in controller implementation but in abstract/generic class, often Spring beans etc... but next questions could be "what is that map? what is in that map? etc... :) I'm just kidding :)

Answer (score 0):

It's Strategy Pattern, but there some stuff should be added.

- The context classes are redundant. In Strategy Pattern there is no such requirement. So basically, you could use "Type to interface not to the implementation" rule there. Instead of having those context classes you could do this.

  ```
  public class Context {

  protected Operation OP;    

  public Context(Operation OP) {
     this.OP = OP;
  }

  public float doStuff(float a,float b){
         OP.run(a,b);
  }

  }
  ```
- Then your client classes can instantiate Context class with custom *Strategies*.

Answer (score 0):

A bunch of people are saying that it is Strategy pattern, but I disagree. Strategy pattern requires that you can change the Operation of the Context. This is more of a weird, degenerate Command pattern.

[This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern#Strategy_and_open.2Fclosed_principle) explains it with a real-life example.